# Core Data - Creating Additional Attributes or Structuring Data

Tags: ios, arrays, database, swift, core-data

I am working on a project where the user would be able to save an image, with a caption and title, and then have it saved using Core Data. The issue I am having is trying to add an album, where users could keep similar images, with captions. I am new to CoreData and have spent all day viewing documentation and combing through Stackoverflow.

I have attached an image (certainly not an artist) of the basic layout I am looking for.[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVLWp.png)

I have also attached an image of what I believe the data structure would look like. [Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt8Hy.png)

The parts tabbed with red are the issues I am having structuring. I have already structured what I believe would be the 'Top' layer of the data structure.

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    let saveData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ScannedItem", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let imageRep = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

    saveData.setValue(textTitle, forKey: "savedTitle")
    saveData.setValue(scannedText, forKey: "savedText")
    saveData.setValue(imageRep, forKey: "savedImage")


    do{
        try context.save()
    }catch{
        print("Failed")
    }
```

How would I go about adding a lower level of data, one to hold a group of strings and one to hold a group of images?

I have been trying to structure it for hours and simply can not figure it out.

I hope the images can add context to what I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I go about adding a lower level of data, one to hold a group of strings and one to hold a group of images?

Don't have a group of strings and a separate group of images (how would you know which string belongs to which image?).  A `ScannedItem` object already has both the string and the image, so you should group `Scanned Item` objects together to make an album.

In CoreData terms, you would create a new entity, `Album`.  That entity might have its own attributes, such as a `albumName` or a `albumDescription`, plus a relationship to represent the `ScannedItems` in the album.  Since an `Album` is a collection of many `ScannedItems`, the relationship would be "to-many".

In CoreData, if you define a relationship from one entity to another, you should always create the inverse relationship as well.  The question to ask yourself is whether each `ScannedItem` can be in more than one `Album`?  If so, the inverse relationship is also "to-many"; if not, the inverse is "to-one".

By default, CoreData represents the collection of objects in a to-many relationship as a Set.  This has two consequences:

- first, there is no implicit ordering of the objects in a set.  If the order is important, you could either make the relationship "ordered" (in which case CoreData uses an ordered set), or you could specify a sort order (eg. in ascending alphabetical order of title) when you access the objects in the relationship.  If the user can pick and choose the order in an `Album`, you might need to explicitly model the sort order by adding a `sortOrder` attribute.  That's easy enough if the relationship from `ScannedItem` to `Album` is to-one, but if the relationship is to-many, the `ScannedItem` might be the first image in one `Album` but the last image in a different `Album`.
- second, a set can only hold a given object once.  So an `Album` cannot contain the same `ScannedItem` more than once.

The solution for each is the same: create a *third* entity, which you might call an `AlbumScanReference`, which has a `sortOrder` attribute, a to-one relationship to `Album` and a to-one relationship to `ScannedItem`.  The inverse relationships would both be to-many: an `Album` could have many `AlbumScanReferences` and a `ScannedItem` could also have many `AlbumScanReferences`.

If `myScan1` was the first item in `album1` and seventh item in `album2`, you would create two `AlbumScanReferences`:

```
let reference1 = ....
reference1.scannedItem = myScan1
reference1.album = album1
reference1.sortOrder = 1

let reference2 = ....
reference2.scannedItem = myScan1
reference2.album = album2
reference2.sortOrder = 7
```

Likewise if `myScan2` was the second item and the eighth item in `album1`, you would have two `AlbumScanReferences`:

```
let reference3 = ....
reference3.scannedItem = myScan2
reference3.album = album1
reference3.sortOrder = 2

let reference4 = ....
reference4.scannedItem = myScan2
reference4.album = album1
reference4.sortOrder = 8
```